# OpenGraph Teams API - SetStatusMessage - Missing option: "show when people message me"

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

[According to the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/presence-setstatusmessage?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-body), I was able to set a status message, like so:

```
SetStatusMessagePostRequestBody requestBody = ConstructMessageBody(statusMessage);
await graphServiceClient.Users[userId].Presence.SetStatusMessage.PostAsync(requestBody);

private static SetStatusMessagePostRequestBody ConstructMessageBody(string content)
{

    DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime endOfDay = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, today.Day, 23, 59, 59, DateTimeKind.Local);
    return new SetStatusMessagePostRequestBody()
    {
        StatusMessage = new PresenceStatusMessage
        {
            Message = new ItemBody
            {
                Content = content,
                ContentType = BodyType.Text
            },
            ExpiryDateTime = new DateTimeTimeZone
            {
                DateTime = endOfDay.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffff"),
                TimeZone = "W. Europe Standard Time"
            }

        }
    };
}
```

What's missing is the option: `show when people message me` as seen in the screenshot here:
[image: Teams Screemshot]

The documentation of the [presenceStatusMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/presencestatusmessage?view=graph-rest-1.0) is not very verbose. The IntelliSense offers another property called `AdditionalData`.

GitHub CodePilot may hallucinate with the following suggestion:
[image: Github Copilot]

But even there, I do not see anything that is close to `show when people message me`. I'd expect a simple boolean that I can pass along with the message. Any ideas?